# Where can I find at least two great online tutorials for building a Web application with the Spring Framework

Tags: java, spring

I'm really disappointed with just about everything I find online that tries to teach the Spring Framework. This is by far the best tutorial I have found yet, because it clearly teaches how to build a simple Web application with Spring:

http://maestric.com/en/doc/java/spring

I need a few more like this to get started, but most of the answers to this question are the same -- buy the Spring in Action book. I'm sorry, but $50 is too much to swallow when all I really want to know is how do I get started building a Web application.

Are there are any good blog articles or tutorials that show a step-by-step of setting up a Web site or Web application with the Spring Framework? Video tutorials would be helpful too -- possibly something that are like those found here:

http://www.asp.net/learn/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are two:

1. [Spring MVC Step By Step](http://static.springframework.org/docs/Spring-MVC-step-by-step/)
2. [Spring Finance](http://stsmedia.net/spring-finance-part-1-introduction-architecture/)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.ervacon.com/products/springwebflow/index.html

Demo of deployed applications.
http://spring.ervacon.com/